# Add class to Previous / Next Button

Tags: 8, webforms

In Webform 7 I was able to add classes to the Previous / Next Page button but can't seem to be able to do this with Webform 8.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to 'Customize' your submit buttons via the button/link at the bottom of the form builder.

[image: Webform form builder]